# Using Exim and Google Apps email as smarthost

Tags: ubuntu, email, g-suite, exim, smarthost

I have a server setup to use exim4 and google apps as my smarthost. But I get errors when the to address is not the one I use to authenticate to google and it seems to drop all return addresses that are not the one it uses to authenitcate.

Example:
On the contact form of my server a user sets user@company1.com as their return address and uses the form to send a message.

I get an email sent to the admin's address admin@myCompany.com but the return address is also now admin@myCompany.com I have no idea of the return address the user set on the form.

I get around this by putting a bad email address in the form's default so Exim4 sends an error message to admin@myCompany.com with the user's email in the debug info.

Clearly I either have it set up wrong or do not understand how smarthosts work (probably both).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google as a smarthost, they will set the From: address to the address you used to authenticate to Google. They do this on purpose, presumably to prevent spam. If you need a smarthost to forward your mail **without** altering your headers, I recommend [Mailhop Outbound](http://www.dyndns.com/services/mailhop/outbound.html) - I used them before and never had any issues...

Answer (score 0):

As the poster mentions above, Google definitely will be restricting the envelope sender and the header From, or else it would lead to widespread abuse.

This problem can solved at a couple of other places, one is your form script, where you can add the form sender in the data itself or else if you want to solve this in exim, I would suggest you write a [system filter](http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch43.html) using the exim filter language which would strip out the From and envelope sender and put in the correct email address for the From and add the form email in a header like X-Form-Submitter-Email.